# Reset default behaviour of spacebar button

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, onclick

I am working on an application in which I have integrated multiple instances of inline CKEDITOR in a single page.

Due to some conflict with javascript/jquery plugin spacebar button is not working(i guess somewhere event.preventDefault() is used for spacebar click event) and I am unsuccessful to trace it.

I want to **reset the behavior of spacebar button**.

Can you please help me with this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I am not able to trace the code else i would have added return false to it. Thanks for your valuable comment

Comment: Did you ever manage to fix this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Check out for the **event.stopPropagation()** method, it can also the cause this behavior.